# Angular2 Cannot find name Iterable in core

Tags: angular

I have lately upgraded my angular project to use the latest 4.0.0-beta.7 version. However I keep getting the following error :

```
@angular\core\src\change_detection\differs\iterable_differs.d.ts:14: TS2304 Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
export declare type NgIterable<T> = Array<T> | Iterable<T>;
```

Any idea how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Were you able to find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

In my main.ts I removed

```
/// <reference path="./../typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts" />
```

and added

```
///<reference path="./../typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts"/>
```

which fixed the issue, hope this helps.

Comment: typings/index.d.ts looks a little different:

/// <reference path="globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/jasmine/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/node/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="modules/es6-promise/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="custom/jquery-slick/index.d.ts" />

can you tell me what i need to change here?

Comment: <reference path="globals/core-js/index.d.ts" /> gives me a "not found"

Comment: got it. i needed `"lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2015.iterable"]` in my tsconfig.json

Comment: @DerZyklop, your solution in tsconfig.json worked for me, can you explain it or i will keep thinking is just magic? :D. Thanks in any case

Comment: @Mikel tbh im not completely sure. it was more like try'n'error. And it braught me other, new issues later on. So since 4.0.2 i had to change tsconfig.json to: `"lib": ["es2015", "dom"]`. Don‘t ask why :/

Comment: @Mikel plus i had to remove the es6-shim folder from ./typings/...

Comment: The `./typings` directory is no longer a supported 'definition' target it was deprecated a while ago in exchange for the `@types` in the `node_modules` folder. Also be aware that NPM packages are now carrying their index.d.ts, so TSC has been updated to handle most of those scenarios, still has issue with momentjs though.